# Julia Gadfly error: add_plot_element not found

Tags: julia, gadfly

Using Julia 0.3.10 with Juno as IDE and Gadfly latest one. Tried running a sample code, but got stuck with `add_plot_element not defined` error message. The last line throws the error. Running on Win8 64bit. I'm sure I'm missing something.

```
using Gadfly

xs = [0:0.1:pi]
k = layer(x=xs, y=sin(xs))
p = plot(x=xs, y=sin(xs))
add_plot_element(k, Guide.title("Now it has a title"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `add_plot_element` is modifying, so you need the `!` like:

`add_plot_element!(k,Guide.title(...))`

This function is also not exported from Gadfly, so you would really need to write:

`Gadfly.add_plot_element!(k, Guide.title("Now it has a title"))`

except `add_plot_element!` doesn't work on Gadfly layers! It does, however, work on plots. What should work:

`Gadfly.add_plot_element!(p, Guide.title("Now it has a title"))`

since the layer itself doesn't have `Guide.Title` elements, but the plot does.

Comment: Geez, even the gadfly github page misses this point. Thanks for replying.